# {} в строке python

Tags: python, format

```
"Привет {}".format( "мир" }
```

Как вставить {} в строку чтобы **format** воспринимал их ак ломаные кавычки. Это нужно для других **format** которые будут применены к строке позже, с другими данными которых пока нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("Привет {}{{}}".format("мир"))
#Привет мир{}
```